# How to get the avatar of a Skype bot's contacts?

Tags: node.js, botframework, avatar

I have a botframework nodejs skype bot, which is used to actively send alarm messages to customers through the ID of the contact (for example, format: 29:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx). It currently works well. He can get the name of the contact, but currently cannot get the avatar of the contact. Is there any way to get the avatar of the contact, such as how to use nodejs SDK or API to achieve this function, thank you very much

Comment: Linking: https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/6177

Comment: Thanks,But is there any way to get the avatar of skypebot‘s contacts?